# How to make image responsive inside a div

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

My code is as Follows:

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="bcd">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
        </a>
        <a>
            <h3>Some Text</h3>
        </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="bcd">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
        </a>
        <a>
            <h3>Some Text</h3>
        </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="bcd">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
        </a>
        <a>
            <h3>Some Text</h3>
        </a> 
    </div>
    <div class="bcd">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
        </a>
        <a>
            <h3>Some Text</h3>
        </a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the image responsive for Mobile(360X640px) and iPad(768X1024px)?
Can you please give me the CSS Code?

I have to give two Images in Mobile and Four in iPad in one line!!

Answer (score 37):

Here is the code you need to follow :

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
```

Refer : http://html5hub.com/html5-picture-element/

Answer (score 4):

set width and height in percentage

```
  <img class="img1" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

use media query

/* Landscape */

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {

 //use your style for landscape
                                          }
```

/* Portrait (i.e. narrow viewport) */

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {

// your style for portrait
                                          }
```

Comment: I have to give two Images in Mobile and Four in iPad in one line!!

Answer (score 4):

Remove `width` and `height` attribute from `img` tag and add in CSS file for this image `max-width:100%; width:100%;`

Answer (score 3):

this setting the image you want to set as a background image in a div and give set the background size as cover

```
background-image: url('YOUR URL');
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using media query you can divide the images as you like.

```
.abc{padding:0; margin:0; box-sizing:border-box; width:100%;}
.bcd{display:inline-block;width:24%;}
@media all and (max-width: 360px){
   .bcd
   {
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
   }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K6NR6/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
 <style>
        html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,time, mark, audio, video {  margin: 0;  padding: 0; border: 0;  font-size: 100%;    font: inherit;  vertical-align: baseline;}/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {    display: block;}body {  line-height: 1;}ol, ul {    list-style: none;}blockquote, q {   quotes: none;}blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after {   content: '';    content: none;}table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;}
        .container .bcd{float: left;position: relative;}
        .container .bcd div{background-color: #fff;border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;border-radius: 5px;margin-top: 10px;min-height: 100px;}
        .container .bcd div img{border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;height: auto;width: 100%;}
        .container .bcd div a.bottom{background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;bottom: 4px;color: #000;font-size: 14px;padding: 9px 0 5px;position: relative;width: 100%;display: inline-block;}
        .container .bcd div a.bottom h3{padding: 0 10px;}
        @media (max-width: 700px) {
            .bcd{width: 100%;}
            .bcd div{margin: 0 10px}
        }
        @media (min-width: 700px) {
            .bcd {width: 50%;}
            .bcd:nth-child(odd) div {margin-left: 10px;margin-right: 5px;}
            .bcd:nth-child(even) div {margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 10px;}
        }
    </style>

<div class="container">
        <div class="bcd">
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img  class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
                </a>
                <a class="bottom"><h3>Some Text</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bcd">
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img  class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
                </a>
                <a class="bottom"><h3>Some Text</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bcd">
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img  class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
                </a>
                <a class="bottom"><h3>Some Text</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bcd">
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
                </a>
                <a class="bottom"><h3>Some Text</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bcd">
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
                </a>
                <a class="bottom"><h3>Some Text</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bcd">
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img  class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
                </a>
                <a class="bottom"><h3>Some Text</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bcd">
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img  class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
                </a>
                <a class="bottom"><h3>Some Text</h3></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bcd">
            <div>
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img1" width="50" height="50"/>
                </a>
                <a class="bottom"><h3>Some Text</h3></a>
            </div>
       </div>
        <div style="clear: both;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;"></div>
    </div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/maulikshekhada/TDfF5/)

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="img" src="image.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {    
        .abc .bcd{max-width:100%;height:auto;border:1px solid #ff0000;width:24%;display:inline-block;}
        .abc .bcd a img{width:100%;height:auto;}
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) { 
        .abc .bcd{max-width:100%;height:auto;border:1px solid #ff0000;width:48%;display:inline-block;}
        .abc .bcd a img{width:100%;height:auto;}
    }
    </style>
```

You can remove the border.

If you remove border, then you can use width 25% for 4 rows in one line and 50% for 2 rows in one line.