# PHP: Make image saved in database responsive when called

Tags: php, html

I have a website that has many categories, each category has it own assigned image stored inside my db, so when a product from lets say bikes appears on the website, the bikes image is called, and when a products from the category chairs is called, the assigned chair image from the DB appears as a header for that products page.

My problem here is how would i make this image responsive as it is saved in the DB, do i make the div the image appears in responsive, or is there another and more efficient way around it.

```
 <div id='image'>
            <?php
            mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
            if (isset($_GET['rest_id'])) {

                $Rest = $_GET['rest_id'];

                $get_cat_img = "SELECT Cuisine_category,Category_img
   FROM Rest_Category
   INNER JOIN Rest_Details
   ON Rest_Category.CategoryID = Rest_Details.Cat_ID
   WHERE Rest_Details.Resturant_ID='$Rest'";

                $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_cat_img) or die("query is not working");
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results) or die("q not working");
                $img = $row['Category_img'];

                echo'<img id="img" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($img) . '" alt="Category_header" width="100%" height="300px">';     
            }
            mysqli_close($dbc);
  ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695992/how-to-make-image-responsive-inside-a-div

Answer (score 2):

You can set width and height in css to make the image responsive.

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

If you have trouble in any particular device, then you can go for media query. EG:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    img {
      width: 100% !important;
      height: auto !important;
    }
}
```

Also [refer](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/).

Answer (score 1):

When we store the images in DB its very slow. So please avoid that option.
Display the images in responsive you just write media queries for different devices